# Regex get last word of pattern

Tags: regex, vb.net

i have this string

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;this is some text</p>
```

`&nbsp;` can be any number of times

to match i am using regex `(?<=<p.*?>*&nbsp;)(.*)(?=</p>)`

but i am getting `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;this is some text` as output

How to get `this is some text`

**EDIT**

i am sorry my string is `<p class='randomstring'>a)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;this is some text</p>`
in place of `a)` there is digit some times.

Comment: `(?<=<p.*?>&nbsp;).*;(.*)(?=</p>)` try this

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=<p[^>]*>)(?:&nbsp;)+(.*)(?=</p>)
```

And grab the **captured group #1** for you match, that will be:

```
this is some text
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question try this regex:

```
(?<=<p[^>]*>)[^)]*\) *(?:&nbsp;)+(.*)(?=</p>)
```

Comment: It works pretty well with your input text `<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;this is some text</p>` If you provide a text for which it doesn't work then I can tweak it further.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the below regex which uses variable length positive lookbehind.

```
(?<=<p[^>]*>(?:&nbsp;)+)\b.*?(?=</p>)
```

This should match only the string `this is some text`

Update:

```
(?<=<p[^>]*>\w*\)(?:&nbsp;)+)\b.*?(?=</p>)
```

Comment: bro all messed up.. filled with &nbsp;  i just want `this is some text`

Comment: but in the demo it works.. You need to replace the matched characters with an empty string.

Comment: i dont know?? can you just implement something in my regex that i posted?? plz

Comment: Bro please see will my Edit change the regex. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `in place of a) there is digit some times.` , you mean like `88)` . See my update.